# How to /testforblock in the overworld from the nether

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Now I already know how to do the setup for the chambers for both sides, but my problem is when the chamber is closed off and the door to the portal is open from one side, the door on the other side might be closed making it impossible to get through whatever side you're trying to get to.

At first I tried experimenting with the command in the overworld like this:

```
/testforblock x y z minecraft:stone_button 2 {Dimension:-1}
```

But it didnt work out.

What I'm trying to get at is when you open the door to the portal you're also opening it from the other side as well closing the chambers and vice versa.

Comment: Just a wild guess: Use `/testforblock x y z minecraft:stone_button 2{Dimension:-1}` (Just remove the space between the extra dimension specifier

Comment: Nothing, it is testing if it is in the Overwold. I'm starting to think it may not be possible for interdimensional commands

Answer (score 3):

Sorry, but it's not possible. You would have to have both the Nether and Overworld loaded at the same time.

I tested it by using /execute to an armor stand in the Nether from the Overworld. So the problem is the Nether not being loaded when you're in the Overworld.

Comment: So my options are pretty much doing everything manually and hope nobody gets lock in the chambers. Hopefully in the next update or future updates may fix this problem.

Answer (score 1):

This is trivial in Minecraft 1.13:

```
/execute in overworld if block x y z minecraft:stone_button
```

(`/testforblock` no longer exists; it was merged into `/execute`)